# Google Sheets: Is there a way for only one user to be notified if anyone changes values in a range of cells to a specific value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that's open most of the time on the desk of multiple users indicating progress on orders. One data point that the person entering the order enters is the priority #. I want it to put a dialog box on the screen of a specific user (the order fulfillment person) when an order is set to priority one, regardless of which page he is on.

```
    function onEdit(e){
  {
    var editRange = { //where New Order information is entered:
    top : 2,
    bottom : 299,
    left : 3,
    right : 4
  };
    //Is it in the right sheet for a new order?
   var thisSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet()
    if (thisSheet.getName() != "Sheet1") return;
  // Exit if we're out of range
  var thisRow = e.range.getRow();
  if (thisRow < editRange.top || thisRow > editRange.bottom) return;

  var thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
    //This part, right here:
    **if (thisCol == 8 && e.range.getValue()=='1') {SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("An order has been moved to priority One.")
    return;}**

    
  if (thisCol < editRange.left || thisCol > editRange.right) return;

  // We're in range; timestamp the edit
  var ss = e.range.getSheet();
  ss.getRange(thisRow,14)   // "G" is column 7
    .setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/YYYY"); 
 
    
}
```

The code surrounding it adds a date stamp to any new or changed orders. I was hoping I could put it in the same cascading "If"s because it comes from the same page. It currently *only* notifies the person who made the change. If notifying just a specific user isn't possible, notifying everyone with the spreadsheet currently open would also be an acceptable outcome.
I would also like it to display which order has been updated to priority one in the dialogue box, but that's just string manipulation and I can probably make it work.

I have a picture with fake data:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9WO2.png

Comment: You may be able to get the desired behaviour by deploying the script as an add-On to be installed by all your users. Another workaround I can think of is to create a comment on the document and assign it to the person handling fullfillment. This will send an email alert too. Let me know what you think

Comment: I think it you use and installable onEdit trigger you should be able to send an email.  Everyone will have authorize it.